# Retain Quote Billing & Shipping Country ELSE assign Location based on IP (Geolocation)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Information:**

WooCommerce version:        3.6.2

WordPress version:      5.1.1

YITH WooCommerce Request A Quote Premium        by YITH – 2.1.7

---

**Objective:**

If a customer is checking out using a Quote then retain the Billing and Shipping country set with the Quote, else restrict the country using Geolocation

If it helps, the Quote url sent to the customer looks like this:
mysite/request-quote/?request_quote=330&status=accepted&raq_nonce=ad5c139f3d7a59993a4ff679d84de3a3&lang

---

**My Code attempt**

```
// GeoIP Country
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'vals_woo_checkout_country' );
function vals_woo_checkout_country( $fields ) {
//check if Billing & Shipping is ALREADY set, if yes use it
if (isset($_POST['billing_country'])) {
$billing_country  = WC()->customer->get_country();
$shipping_country = ! empty( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()  )  ? WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() : $billing_country;
}
//If not set then use geolocation to set
else
//Only in Checkout and in Order Pay
if ( (is_checkout()) && (is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') )) {
            $geoData = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
            $Geocountries = WC()->countries->get_countries();
            $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
                'options' => array(
                    $geoData['country'] => $Geocountries[$geoData['country']]
                ),
                'class' => array(
                    'form-row-wide',
                    'address-field',
                    'update_totals_on_change'
                )
            );
            $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
                'options' => array(
                    $geoData['country'] => $Geocountries[$geoData['country']]
                ),
                'class' => array(
                    'form-row-wide',
                    'address-field',
                    'update_totals_on_change'
                )
            );
}
            return $fields;
        }
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;

    $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // On "update" checkout form event
        $(document.body).on('update_checkout', function(){
            $('#billing_country_field label > .optional').remove();
    $('.woocommerce-checkout #billing_country_field').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            $('#shipping_country_field label > .optional').remove();
    $('.woocommerce-checkout #shipping_country_field').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_filter( 'wp_footer' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label_script' );
//end code
```

**Update 03/May/2019**

This code does NOT work.

Any help on this is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "does NOT work"?

Comment: @NicoHaase: I am getting a whole lot of errors when I visit the site under both the conditions. Can you help?

Comment: Why don't you share some of these errors?

Comment: @NicoHaase: Actually I am rethinking my approach which may not need this code. I am working on this new approach now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally thought this over and have a different solution.

**Part 1 - Settings**
Under Woocommerce -> Settings -> General -> Default customer location = Geolocate
[image: Woocommerce setting]

**Part 2 - Code**
Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

```
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) return;
    $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        // On "update" checkout form event remove option to select countries
        $(document.body).on('update_checkout', function(){
            $('#billing_country_field label > .optional').remove();
    $('.woocommerce-checkout #billing_country_field').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            $('#shipping_country_field label > .optional').remove();
    $('.woocommerce-checkout #shipping_country_field').css('pointer-events', 'none');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_filter( 'wp_footer' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label_script' );
```

This works for me for now. I would really be grateful if anyone could suggest a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

```html
function wpse_287199_woo_checkout_country( $fields ) {
    $geoData = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
    $countries = WC()->countries->get_countries();

    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            $geoData['country'] => $countries[$geoData['country']]
        ),
        'class' => array(
            'form-row-wide',
            'address-field',
            'update_totals_on_change'
        )
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Country', 'woocommerce'),
        'options' => array(
            $geoData['country'] => $countries[$geoData['country']]
        ),
        'class' => array(
            'form-row-wide',
            'address-field',
            'update_totals_on_change'
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wpse_287199_woo_checkout_country' );
```

Comment: Thanks Manish. This just assigns Shipping & Billing Location based on IP (Geolocation). I need **conditional** assignment as mentioned by me in the objective.